# Joomla insert query not success

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

I have need some help. i want to insert data into my database but for ip address query not success

```
$ipaddr = getHostByName(php_uname('n'));

$columns = array('yes', 'no', 'ipadd');

$values = array($yes,$no,$ipaddr);
$query
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__jkyesno'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
    ->values(implode(',', $values))
 ->where('ipadd != '. $ipaddr);
```

query gives an error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: I disagree with this,  the question is specifically about the Joomla query API. However it is potentially a "debug my code" question.  Try doing `echo $query->dump();`  and see what the generated query is. This will help you identify where the problem is.

Comment: try using this $query
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__jkyesno'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
    ->values(implode(',', $values))
 ->where('ipadd != '. $db->qn($ipaddr));

Comment: Try quote rather than qn for the last clause,